# how do you change Boolean value of all variable with one function?

Tags: python, oop

i want to turn values of plug1,plug2 and smartdoor with one function `turnallonall` i dont undertsand how to do it because every time i will have to pass values to parameters

```
class smartHome():
    def __init__(self):
        self.devices = []
        
    def getDevices(self):
        return self.devices
    
    def getDeviceAt(self,index):
        self.devices[index]
         
    def addDevice(self,device):
         self.devices.append(device)
    
    def toggleSwitch(self,index):
        self.devices[index].toggle_Switch()
```

so far i am using loop and able to alter values but its not ideal i want one function that can alter all Boolean value.

```
      for i in range(3):
         Smarthome.toggleSwitch(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot to `return` the `self.devices[index]` inside `getDeviceAt`.
- Use Python's naming convention for your methods.

There is nothing wrong with for loop. Just put it inside your class. It needs to call devices' `toggle_method()` function.

```py
class SmartHome:
    def __init__(self):
        self.devices = []

    def get_devices(self):
        return self.devices

    def add_device(self, device):
        self.devices.append(device)

    def toggle_switch_device(self, index):
        self.devices[index].toggle_switch()

    def toggle_all(self):
        for device in self.devices:
            device.toggle_switch()


class Device:
    def __init__(self, name, power) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.power = power

    def toggle_switch(self):
        self.power = not self.power


s = SmartHome()
s.add_device(Device("plug1", False))
s.add_device(Device("plug2", True))
s.add_device(Device("smartdoor", True))

s.toggle_all()

print([(device.name, device.power) for device in s.get_devices()])
```

output:

```
[('plug1', True), ('plug2', False), ('smartdoor', False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Device class should have instance like `is_on`. `toggleSwitch` method need to be in device class and not in smarthome.

```
class Device:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_on = kwargs.get("is_on", False)
  
  def toggle_switch(self):
     # do something
     self.is_on = not self.is_on


class SmartHome:
    def __init__(self, devices: list[Device] | None):
        self.__devices = devices
        
    def get_devices(self):
        return self.__devices
    
    def get_device_at_index(self, index):
        return self.__devices[index]
         
    def add_device(self, device):
         self.__devices.append(device)
   
    def all_on(self):
       for device in self.__devices:
           if not device.is_on:
              device.toggle_switch()

home = SmartHome(devices=[Phone, Door, Light])
home.all_on()
```